# How to deal with API sometimes returning a property as an array and sometimes as an object?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Can anyone see the problem here? the object "OrderItemPayment" becomes an array for some reason during deserialisation?

When I try to deserialize a response that looks like this:

[image]

I get this result:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "created_at":"2021-01-28 18:37:45",
         "payment":[
            
         ]
      },
      {
         "created_at":"2021-01-28 16:06:23",
         "payment":[
            
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**My classes**

```
[Serializable]
public class Order
{
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public OrderItem[]? Items { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class OrderItem
{
    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public string? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("payment")]
    public OrderItemPayment Payment { get; set; } = new OrderItemPayment();
}
[Serializable]
public record OrderItemPayment
{
    [JsonProperty("amount_paid")]
    public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("shipping_captured")]
    public decimal ShippingCaptured { get; set; }
}
```

*My result:*
[image]

Comment: Payment in your initial screenshot and in your model is a single object. In the result (`response.Content`) that you've shown, it's an array.

Comment: @Llama yes that’s my problem. Since payment is an object it should resolve as an object and not an array but I don’t understand why.

Comment: So is your question really "how to deal with API sometimes returning a property as an array and sometimes as an object?"

Comment: @Llama that was a much better title and yes that’s my question really.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix your OrderItem, according to a screen shot

```
public partial class OrderItem
    {
    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public string? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("payment")]
    public List<OrderItemPayment> Payment { get; set; }
}
```

and according to your screen shot Payment should be deserialized as []

Comment: the response from postman shows that payment is an object and contains data such as amount_paid.. but when I try to get the data from a restsharp client and deserialize it according to my model the OrderItemPayment object converts to an array for some reason.

Comment: @Hannes Response doesnt' convet data to anything. It just shows a real json object.

Comment: I just changed the title so it’s easier to understand my problem.

Comment: @Hannes The problem is the API not the client side seialization. The API is not returning payment data.